# How make an area on win form scrollable?

Tags: c#, winforms

Items like below have to be accommodated on a specific area on WinForm.

"Order 1         ------------        Time Left: 00:20:00" 
"Order 2         ------------        Time Left: 01:30:20"

We should be able to perform the following action on the each order:

1. Each item will occupy not more than one line. As the area specified
   for it on the win form is limited, as more items comes in, I want to
   make the area scrollable.
2. According to the time left the background color of the line should also change.
3. There is a DONE button next to it. So, if the item is selected and DONE is pressed, the item is moved off the list.

My question is what C# Form control can be used for it. I was thinking of labels, but how to make the area scrollable if there are many of them. If not labels, what else is suggested?

Comment: Nothing that a ListView with View = Details could not do.

Comment: I'd use DataGridView.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comments, you can use grid, but in case it does not suits your requirements, this is like something what you can do -

- Create a custom user control which will have a label control for your order detail and a *Done* button. Something like this (*sure you will design it better!*). The label will be empty initially and you will pass then from outside, using a public property for example, while creating the control.

[image]

- Define an `Event` on this control, and raise this event when the *Done* button is clicked. This is required for your main form to know that when to remove this user control.
- Add a `FlowLayoutPanel` to your main form. This will be the container for your user controls. Make sure to set the following so that the controls are created as desired

`this.flowLayoutPanel1.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;`

`this.flowLayoutPanel1.WrapContents = false;`

`this.flowLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = true;`

- Now you can start adding your custom control to this `FlowLayoutPanel`, either by loop or the way you like. The control will added in linear way, one in each line, and you will also get scroll it it exceeds the given space.
- Make sure to define event handler for the control, so that you know when to remove the control. And of course you can set other properties like back groung color etc. That's not going to be any problem.